# Can I somehow get details from android key alias? like validity, organisation and so on

Tags: android, key, keystore

Can I somehow get details from android key alias? like validity, organisation and so on...
I lost my key and keystore files, but I remember all passwords, is there any way how can I get this information from existing apk file?

All I need to do is just export new version of my application and I want it to replace previous after installation.

THX

Comment: does it have to have a specific key? it should export and work fine with any key you generate.

Comment: Toadzky - it will export and run, but if user1602687 is trying to update an app, then it will not work

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, there is no way to replace a lost keystore. Once it is lost you cannot get it back, do your best to find it, but failing this the best you can do is publish a new app(with a new keystore), and tell your users to install the new app for updates.

**Make sure you backup your new key store**, send it to yourself via email, put it in a cloud, and put it on a different computer so that doesn't happen again.

Even if you knew the details that you put in your old keystore you could not recreate it - keystores are designed to be impossible to recreate.

Just in case you want another source:

- https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/tcmT2uHOmGY