# I can't update my apk

Tags: android, publishing, keystore, signing

I made an app and successfully published into the Play Store. Then I discovered a bug and fixed it. Now I can't update the app because it says that the certificate of the two apks are different.

Using the Eclipse signing tool, I tried filling in the same things I wrote the previous time, but that's not it. I saw that if I link the old apk, I can use the "use existing keystore", although I can't select an alias.

If I try to create a new keystore and fill in the same things as before I get a "keytool error: java.io.IOException: Invalid Keystore format".

Please tell me how I can update my published apk.

Comment: If you select "use existing keystore" and can select the original keystore you used to create it, but aren't able to select an alias, then you are not entering the correct password for the keystore. Any chance you're not remembering/entering that password correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just posted this answer here - [Can I somehow get details from android key alias? like validity, organisation and so on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13366644/can-i-somehow-get-details-from-android-key-alias-like-validity-organisation-an/13366856#13366856) - not the same question, but it has the same answer -

Sorry, there is no way to replace a lost keystore. Once it is lost you cannot get it back, do your best to find it, but failing this the best you can do is publish a new app(with a new keystore), and tell your users to install the new app for updates.

**Make sure you backup your new key store**, send it to yourself via email, put it in a cloud, and put it on a different computer so that doesn't happen again.

Even if you knew the details that you put in your old keystore you could not recreate it - keystores are designed to be impossible to recreate.

Just in case you want another source:

- https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/tcmT2uHOmGY

Comment: oh my godness...
reading your post I thought that the damn eclipse didn't give me nothing made exception for the apk file... and you were somewhat saying that should had a sort of keystore file...

Comment: Sorry to break the bad news, you are relatively lucky if you only have one app, the guy in the link has 20

Comment: oh my godness...
reading your post I thought that the damn eclipse didn't give me nothing made exception for the apk file... and you were somewhat saying that should had a sort of keystore file... then I realized that I found a weird file on the same folder with myapp.apk called myapp2.apk with a different icon, I thought it was a somehow corrupted apk which was weird because I launched the signing procedure only one time... **luckily** i didn't erased it but backed it up just to be sure, I tried using that as keystore entry, and it worked!! So thanks for making me think to all this!

Comment: **Backup your keystore asap**

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation and I do the same, is to use GitHub.com or bitbucket.org private repository source control and check in your keystore with your code.